# what does this statement written in jquery cause syntax error on IE7/8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, syntax

I am now writing javascript code, and one of the statement is:

```
if ($(this).is(":select")) {
    if ($(this).find("option").filter(":selected").length > 0) {
        var txt__ = $(this).find("option:selected:eq(0)").val();
        if ($.trim(txt__) != '') {
            flag_ = true;
        }
    }
}
```

On Chrome Firefox and IE9, it is ok. but on ie 7/8, it keeps telling me that 'syntax error', some guy can help me with this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that line. Can you show us the surrounding lines?

Comment: Also try to reproduce the error in a jsFiddle.

Comment: if ($(this).is(":select")) {
    if ($(this).find("option").filter(":selected").length > 0) {
     var txt__ = $(this).find("option:selected:eq(0)").val();
     if ($.trim(txt__) != '') {
      flag_ = true;
     }
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your first line:

```
if ($(this).is(":select")) {
```

EDIT: Fixed response based on OP's comment

I believe either

```
if ($(this).tagName.toLowerCase() == "select") {
```

or

```
if ($(this).is(":input[type=select]")) {
```

should do the trick.

Comment: if ($(this).is(":select")) means if this element is an select type